# Resolve JNDI lookups from Spring application context?

Tags: java, spring, jndi

In our Spring application we use clustered Hibernate Search with ActiveMQ which sets up some objects via JNDI. These objects are configured via the Spring application context and I am looking for a way to resolve JNDI calls to these objects.

All I could find was the JNDI lookups from the Spring context.

We need it the other way around: resolve JNDI lookups from Spring application context.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [recipe by James Strachan](http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=35474#179220) may be the way to go but I need to check.